# Stripe, Charges and Payouts

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am working in a project where users can contribute to campaigns, but funds are not released till campaign ends.

After some research I understood that I need to set payouts as manual and We have a limit of 90 days, after that payment will be done.

I understand this will only work with connected accounts using Stripe Connect. I have already done now using Stripe Connect - Express.

Now I am little confused on how charges and payouts work together.

1. When an user makes a contribution to the campaign I need create a charge. Do I need to create a manual payout at same time?
2. I see payouts have an id, I guess I will need to "execute" payout when campaign ends? is this done through the API? or through the dashboard?
3. At the moment of connecting an account is it possible to set manual payouts as a account property?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have to create manual payout every time a user makes a contribution. you can create a one-time payout when the campaign ends.
2. I don't think you have to execute payout. It automatically get settled in 2-3 days with your bank
3. I didn't notice any such feature to set payout to manual while connecting. You have to make separate call yo [account API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_object-payout_schedule) once account is connected by acting as connected account using secret key returned in response